# MS Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Desktop - C++11 features

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, c++11

I use MS Visual Studio 2012 for Windows Desktop (C++) and I've recently started using C++11 features,such as range-based for loop,lambda functions,`final`,`override` and so on.
But I cannot use some of the features,like `std::initializer_list`,user-defined signatures...
I don't understand why this version of MS Visual Studio does support some,but not all of them.
Should I start using a newer version,or what?
Thanks.

Comment: Because features take a nonzero amount of time to implement. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx

Comment: "newer version" supports more, but still not all, of C++11.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should start using a newer version, because as it happens, newer versions implement new features.

Also, your question doesn't really ask a question.

Answer (score 0):

You can find comparison tables of supported C++11 features in recent versions of Visual Studio on the MSDN website: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh567368.aspx